# What do the eigenvalues of a correlation matrix represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning, correlation

I was wondering if there was any special meaning to the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a correlation matrix. I get what they mean in a covariance matrix, and how that relates to PCA, though. Can you do PCA with the eigenvalues of a correlation matrix instead? What would the PC's mean in that case?

Comment: So does that mean the eigenvalues of a correlation matrix also represent PCs? They are just scaled versions of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix?

Comment: I was hoping to get a conceptual/intuitive understanding of it but I'll try matlab if you think it'll help

Comment: you already have it in my 1st comment ! the advice of matlab is also the advice of writing down all the formulas/equations involved. your "conceptual" question will become rigorous and easy to answer

Comment: @reuns This is just wrong; only if D is isotropic do the eigenvalues simply scale. For an arbitrary diagonal matrix which is the case here no simple relationship exists, and so you cannot relate the eigendecomposition of the covariance and correlation matrices

Comment: @smörkex Yes obviously. Also the correlation matrix is $D  X^\top X D$